# What does infestation do?

Tags: natural-selection-2

Does the Kharaa's infestation do anything other than change who can build there?  Is there any improved regeneration, hive sight provided, or other subtle effects that I'm not noticing?

Answer (score 3):

Infestation does not provide regeneration. Alien commander foresight is not based on infestation. The main thing infestation does is simply control who can build there: Aliens can only place structures on infestation, and Marines can only place structures on non-infested surfaces.

Of note, though, are the following:

- Alien structures no longer on infestation will take damage over time until destroyed, or infestation reclaims the area.
- The alien commander's Bone Wall and Nutrient Mist abilities can only be used on infested ground areas.
- A Gorge's Hydras will grow automatically when placed on infestation. (Hydras placed off of infestation must be grown manually using Heal Spray.)
- Whips become inactive if the infestation they are built upon recedes.

Answer (score 1):

The Gorge's bellyslide is MUCH faster on infestation. Very helpful for outrunning those pesky marines!